# Set prompt in Haskell

Tags: haskell, prompt, ghci

I'm new in Haskell

Instead of the:

```
Prelude>
```

I want GHCi to prompt

```
GHCi>
```

I wrote

```
:set prompt "GHCi> "
```

but when I close GHCi and open it again it show me

```
prelude
```

again.
I saw that I need to create a file called .ghci in my home folder and set its to contents to

```
:set prompt "GHCi> ".
```

How can I create this file and set the prompt.
Thank You for your answers

Comment: this is purely aesthetic: because you'll probably want as little distraction while reading as possible, I recommend using a funky rare-Unicode character to distinguish the prompt, like `› ` (for Haskell)

Comment: even just using a different prompt symbol shape (`›⇨↝▹➵⧽⸖⮕`) can be enough to remind you that you're not in your normal terminal prompt, and there's enough distinct symbols for every interactive CLI you could want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a [`.ghci` file](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) that specifies the configuration of your GHCi environment.

For a *nix system, that is often located at the `~/.ghci`, for a Windows system, that is apparently located at `appdata/ghc/ghci.conf` where `appdata` is often `C:/Documents and Settings/user/Application Data`.

You can thus write to this `.ghci` (or `ghci.conf`) file a set of instructions to do when opening the GHC shell, like:

```
:set prompt "GHCi> "
```

GHCi will furthermore probably require to set the permissions to the file, for example on a Linux system with:

```
chmod go-w ~/.ghci
```

such that the group and other users can not write to the file.

Comment: What system are you on that has a umask that you'd need to `chmod go-w` a newly-created file?

Comment: @JosephSible: often the default umask of a Linux distro gives permissions to the group :)

Comment: I'd like to see the Linux distro that sets umask 002 by default.